# Closing word application from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying, at the beginning of my macro, to close all open Word application instances, although I don't know which documents are open, and I can't set them as an object.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-get-the-instance-of-already-opened-word-document/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will close all running Word documents.

You need `On Error Resume Next` to prevent errors if no Word application instance is running.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CloseWordDocuments()

    Dim objWord As Object
    
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        On Error Go To 0
        If Not objWord Is Nothing Then
            objWord.Quit
            Set objWord = Nothing
        End If
    Loop Until objWord Is Nothing

End Sub
```

*Edit*

Correction below because the loop above has a flaw i.e. it will exit after the  first instance of Word is closed ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CloseWordDocuments()

    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim blnHaveWorkObj As Boolean

    ' assume a Word object is there to be quit
    blnHaveWorkObj = True
    
    ' loop until no Word object available
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If objWord Is Nothing Then
            ' quit loop
            blnHaveWorkObj = False
        Else
            ' quit Word
            objWord.Quit
            ' clean up
            Set objWord = Nothing
        End If
    Loop Until Not blnHaveWorkObj

End Sub
```

Comment: When you use OERN to trap a possible error, you must restore errors handling as soon as possible.  In this case that would be `On Error Go To 0` immediately after `Set objWord ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, it will close Word Application (without saving).

```
Option Explicit

Sub CloseWordWindows()

Dim objWord As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

' if no active Word is running >> exit Sub
If objWord Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you get an error if no Word application instance is running?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie today my keyboard skills are high, already fixed :)  even though I like your loop

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I like the improvement learning here, your loop is so simple (and I hadn't thought of it yet)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `Shell` to accesss the elegance of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

```
Sub Comesfast()
X = Shell("powershell.exe kill -processname winword", 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To close all word files without saving:

```
Sub CloseWordDocumentsWithoutSave()
Dim objWordApp As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

'Attempt to get an existing Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set objWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

'Check if Word application object is successfully set
If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then
    'Loop through all open Word documents and close them without saving
    For Each objDoc In objWordApp.Documents
        objDoc.Close False ' Close without saving changes
    Next objDoc
    
    'Quit Word application
    objWordApp.Quit
    Set objWordApp = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "No open Word documents found.", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```