# Access all documents for Word from multiple instance using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

There are multiple instances of word running in my machine. I require list for all documents from all the instances.
Say Instance 1 has document open name: "*Document 1*" and instance 2 has document open name: "*instance2.docx*"

I am looking for both "*Document 1*" and "*instance2.docx*"

But when I use below code it returns the documents present in first instance ie(only "Document 1")

```vb
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") // this returns the object of first instance only
For Each X In oApp.Documents 
MsgBox X.Name    // will give only document "Document 1"
Next X
```

[Closing word application from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100661/closing-word-application-from-excel-vba) -- checked this but here we need to close the first instance in order to get details of next one.

**Is there any way we can access all the documents without closing the instances?**

Comment: It's possible, and you don't need to kill each instance of Word, but you do need to be careful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633551/word-vba-and-multiple-word-instances

Comment: One way is to use the Win32 EnumWindows function, so search SO for VBA samples for that. For each top-level window you can get the caption, which usually (for Office Products) gives the name of the open file. A second way is to query the Running Object Table for the type of document you are looking for, but I haven't seen any simple VBA examples for doing this (as it requires using the Win32 API).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003586/find-all-open-word-applications-from-within-a-vba-excel-macro for example